# How do you hide a tab bar in Xcode (swift)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tabs

I'm trying to hide the tab bar in Xcode upon entering a different screen. I've tried to do this using the code:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
```

This hides the tab bar but it leaves a black box the size of the tab bar at the bottom of the screen.

I have done some research online and I haven't been able to find a way around it. How do I hide the tab bar without disrupting the view I already have?

*Please provide answers in Swift.*

Comment: did you try tabBarController?.tabBar.alpha = 0?

Comment: Just tried that, still not working. It still displays the black bar at the bottom of the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this. It works for me and I hope it helps you.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true 
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I also forgot to mention that on that same screen I am hiding a navigation bar as well (although that seems to be working properly)